# InfoPlist.strings problem when building

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I removed a localized file. And now when Im trying to build I keep getting this error:

```
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo=0x2025f7cc0 "“InfoPlist.strings” couldn’t be removed." | User info: {
```

I can't find a solution. Any advice?

Im using XCode 4

Comment: Did you delete the InfoPlist.strings ?

Comment: Try cleaning (Product > Clean) your project. It can help you.

Comment: Yes I did delete it. And cleaning doesn't help :(

Comment: OK, that's strange... Try to add InfoPlist.string to your project again and delete it by selecting the file and pressing backspace. Maybe it will help...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Xcode, click on your project in the top left of the first column.  Go to Build Phases and expand the "Copy Bundle Resources".  Make sure that InfoPlist.strings has been removed from this list.  Otherwise the compiler will try to copy it over during compilation but it has already been deleted so it'll fail.

Also, alternatively, try just finding the file in finder and manually deleting it there.

Comment: I have multiple InfoPlist.strings files regarding third party api's also. So how can I delete it?